# Persist byte array to local file with chrome in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, file-upload, arrays

I need to load a file from the local file system, encrypt it and save it back on the local file system using chrome. I start chrome with the `--allow-file-access-from-files` flag.
This is the code used to load the file, convert it into a byte array and encrypt the byte array:

```
var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.responseType = "arraybuffer";
http.open("GET","file.bin",false);
http.send();
var plain = Array.apply([], new Int8Array(http.response));
var encryptedByteArray = encryptFunction(plain);
```

At this point the encrypted array contains the expected bytes, since I've compared it to a working version of the script written in Java.
In the Java application, the byte array is then persisted to disk with:

```
new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("encryptedFromJava")).write(encryptedByteArray)
```

The problem is to write the encrypted byte array to disk in javascript. I've tried with:

```
window.requestFileSystem = window.requestFileSystem || window.webkitRequestFileSystem;
window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 1024*1024, function(fs) {
    fs.root.getFile('encryptedFromJavascript.bin', {create: true}, function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(function(fileWriter) {    
            var blob = new Blob(encryptedByteArray);
            fileWriter.addEventListener("writeend", function() {
                location.href = fileEntry.toURL();
            }, false);
            fileWriter.write(blob);
        }, function() {});
    }, function() {});
}, function() {});
```

but if I perform a `diff` on `encryptedFromJava.bin` and `encryptedFromJavascript.bin`, they differ.
`encryptedByteArray` has the right bytes, I can't figure out how to save it so that won't differ from the encrypted file created via Java.

If I try the writing with a simple array (by replacing encryptedByteArray with a byte array containing `{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }` for example), the file created by Java code contains `^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H` whereas the one created by javascript contains `12345678`.
Also the file created in java is `application/octet-stream`, the one created in javascript is `plain/text`. Initialising the `Blob` object with `{type: 'application/octet-stream'}` doesn't seem to make any difference.

I appreciate this is most likely not the best way to achieve the task, but I would like to understand if it is possible at all to write the file in the same format Java does.

Comment: Can you create a dummy file (e.g. 0x01, 0x02, ...) and try to discern what's changing?

Comment: @StephenThomas: I've replaced the `encryptedByteArray` in the javascript and java code with a simple byte array `{ 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, 0x08 }`. The binary file created in java contains `^A^B^C^D^E^F^G^H`, whereas the one created from javascript contains `12345678`

Comment: `0x01` should be neither `^A` nor `1` …